# To execute Cancel Button in WebView

Tags: android, html

I am using my own html code to show a html page in WebView. I want to close the current activity on click of Cancel Button.
My Code is like:

```
public class WebHtml extends Activity
{
        String historyUrl, baseUrl;
        URL url = null;
        WebView mWebView;

String html = "<html>" + 
                "<body>" +
                "<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='get.html'>" +
                "User <input type='text' name='user'>   <br />" +
                "Password <input type='password' name='user'>   <br />" +
                "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login' />" +
                "<input type='button' value='Cancel' name='Cancel' onClick='javascript:window.close();'' />" +
                "</form>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            mWebView = new WebView(this);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
            mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, "text/html", "utf-8", historyUrl);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            setContentView(mWebView);
        }

        @Override 
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        { 
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) 
            { 
                mWebView.goBack();
                return true; 
            } 
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 

        }

        private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
        { 
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                Log.i("ShowForm", "onPageStarted()" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                historyUrl = url.toString();
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                Log.i("ShowForm", "onPageFinisheded()" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                baseUrl = url.toString();
            }

            @Override 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            { 

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true; 
            } 
        }
}
```

The thing is I am not able to make it close the current form activity. I had used (window.close(), form.close(), javascript:window.close() on onClick but they showed no effect) & (I tried window.unload() which made exception) Moreover System.exit() shuts the app off at the time activity first starts.

Please suggest me what should I do.

Thanks,

Haps.

Comment: put the layout where WebView is present.

Comment: Added the whole page to ques, please take a look.

Comment: yes your are doing ok.just do one thing.create a LinearLayout and also a button along with WebView and add button and webview into linearlayout and set this linearlayout as setContentView(yout_linearLayout);

Comment: Yah, that is a good option. But actually the above code is just a trial. In real I am getting the whole html code as soap response and I just have to show that as an Activity. That code will have a cancel button in it and I have to program that button to cancel the activity.

Comment: try to write a function and inside that function just use finish();. It may work.

Comment: @AndroidKiller: I used that before, it also don't work. On your saying I tried it once more but no effects. :P

Comment: I used it like this::

"<input type='button' value='Cancel' name='Cancel' onClick='"+ cancel()+"' />" +

Comment: "<input type='button' value='Cancel' name='Cancel' onClick='cancel()+"' />.Remove double qoutes.If not working the try to remove single quote too and define your own cancel function and use finish();.It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the onClick of that cancel button to a URL?  Something like `onClick="document.location.href='http://exitActivity';"`.

Then in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, you can intercept that URL and exit the app.

```
@Override 
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (url.contains("http://exitActivity")
        finish();  // close activity
    else
        view.loadUrl(url);

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Triad, I used this code and it took me to http://exitActivity rather than finishing it.

Comment: Oh, maybe try `if (url.contains("exitActivity"))` instead?

Comment: Is there any way if i use class=Classname instead of onclick=xyz?

Comment: Hm, it's easy to do with onClick because the Android webViewClient allows intercepting of clicks/links.  Not sure how you'd do it with classname, sorry!